# Kotlin: loop through finite values returned by a next function

Tags: kotlin, while-loop, iterator, iteration, bufferedreader

### Background info

A common pattern in some programming languages is to have a function that when called, returns the next value until the end of the finite sequence is reached, in which case it keeps returning null.

A common example in Java is this:

```
void printAll(BufferedReader reader) {
    String line;

    // Assigns readLine value to line, and then check if not null
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

It is similar to the `iterator` in the [Iterator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern), but the iterator has a `next(): Object` and a `hasNext(): Boolean`, whereas the [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html) has no `hasNext()` check functionality, but only the form `next(): Object?`, in which the returned object can be null to mark the end of the sequence. I call functions such as `next()` a "*next function*" (or maybe "*yield*" function), but I don't know if there is an word for this pattern.

In Java, an expression can contain assignments, which allows constructs such as: `(line = reader.readLine()) != null`. This code assigns the nullable value of `readLine()` to `line`, and then check whether the value in `line` is not null. But Kotlin doesn't allow such constructs, because in Kotlin, an assignment is not an expression, so it cannot be used as loop condition in Kotlin.

### Question

What are the possible patterns in Kotlin to loop through the finite number of values returned by a next function, such as `readLine()`?
(Next functions can also be found for example in [ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html), to go to the next zip entry.)

I'm not simply looking for a Kotlin workaround for this problem, because I can program that myself without problems. I'm looking to explore the possible patterns so that people can select one that suits their needs.

I have found some patterns myself, which I'll post here as an answer, but there may be more patterns out there, which would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 5):

I've ordered to solutions by (what I believe) the best solution in descending order.

### Solution 1: using built-in `generateSequence` (recommended)

I just found out that Kotlin has a built-in standalone [`generateSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) function (located in the `kotlin.sequences` package).

```
generateSequence { br.readLine() }
    .forEach { line ->
        println("Line: $line")
    }
```

`generateSequence` accepts a code block that you can provide, that must generates a value. In this case, `br.readLine()` is the code block, and generates either a String, or null if the end is reached. `generateSequence` generates a sequence that internally calls `readLine()` when the next value is requested from the sequence, until `readLine()` return null, which terminates the sequence. So sequences in Kotlin are *lazy*: they don't read neither know all the values ahead of time, only a single `readLine()` is called when for example `forEach` processes a single line. This laziness is usually exactly what you want, because it saves memory and minimizes an initial delay. To change it to eagerly, you can append `generateSequence { br.readLine() }` with `.toList()`.

- Pros 1: no additional variables.
- Pros 2: just one construct (`generateSequence`).
- Pros 3: returns a `Sequence`, so you can chain additional methods such as `filter()`.
- Pros 4: any sign of nullability is abstracted away. (No `null` keywords, nor `?` nor `!` operators.)
- Pros 5: adheres a functional programming style.

IMO, this is the cleanest solution that I've seen so far.

### Solution 2: while true loop with elvis break call

```
while (true) {
    val line = br.readLine() ?: break
    println("Line: $line")
}
```

- Pros: no additional variables.
- Cons: some people don't like while-true loops and break statements.

### Solution 3: do-while with safe call `also`

```
do {
    val line = br.readLine()?.also { line ->
        println("Line: $line")
    }
} while (line != null)
```

- Pros: no additional variables.
- Cons: less readable than other solutions.

### Solution 4: `next` before start and at end of each iteration

This is probably the most common solution for Java programmers who are new to Kotlin.

```
var line = br.readLine()
while (line != null) {
    println("Line: $line")
    line = br.readLine()
}
```

- Cons 1: duplicated next (`readLine`) call and a duplicated assignment.
- Cons 2: reassignable var.

### Solution 5: while loop with assignment using `also`

This is the solution generated by IntelliJ when converting Java to Kotlin code:

```
var line: String?
while (br.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
    println("Line: $line")
}
```

Cons: line is declared as nullable, even though it can never be null inside the loop. So you'll often have to use the not-null assertion operator if you want to access members of `line`, which you can limit to one assertion using:

```
var nullableLine: String?
while (br.readLine().also { nullableLine = it } != null) {
    val line = nullableLine!!
    println("Line: $line")
}
```

- Cons 1: requires not-null assertion even though it can never be null inside the loop.
- Cons 2: reassignable var.
- Cons 3: less readable than other solutions.

Note that if you change `var line: String?` to `var line: String`, the code still compiles, but it will throw a NPE when `line` becomes null, even though there are no not-null assertions used.